# Not in a domain, or using AD. Can I give SQL access on one server to a UserGroup on another?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, groups

I have users in a group on one server, and I'd like them all to have access to a particular database on a SQL Server on another server.

Neither server is in a domain, and I'm not using AD.

Is it possible?

Comment: in this case you probably should use sql authentication!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would have to use SQL Server Authentication for that.